# IIS перезапуск сайта через командную строку или же из кода программы

Tags: iis, iis-10

Полскадите как перезапустить сайт на iis ?

Я нашел отличный пример, однако он не работает как требется.

```
"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd stop site qwerty" -- Stops Site 'qwerty'

"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd start site qwerty" -- Starts Site 'qwerty'
```

Этот способ выключает сайт и включает его, но только лишь для пользователей. Т.е. процесс не останавливается, а продолжает работать. Подскажите как мне остановить прочесс полностью и затем вновь запустить его ?

Проект с которым работаю. размещен на iis сервере и написан на asp  .net core. IIS 10

Comment: Команда iisreset

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо большое, вроде работает. но подскажите еще как указать конкретный сайт ? По имени или же по IP::Port ?
Если можено то пример краткий.

Comment: Она весь ИИС сбрасывает.

Comment: @nick_n_a да я это понял, просто хочется узнать есть ли способ точечно конкретный сайт перезапстить а не все целиком

Comment: Сайты сбрасывать - так как у вас в примере, но, это не правильно. Сайт привязан к пулу, и процессы привязаны к пулу, поэтому если вы хотите что бы процессы завершились - нужно делать стоп пулу, и старт пула, к которому привязан сайт, но при этом сбросятся все сайты пула. А по-другому не получится. Что бы сбросить сайт, делают отдельный пул для сайта, и делают привязку один пул - один сайт - тогда сбросом пула сбрасывается сайт.

Comment: понял благодарю